# Run function when header tabs click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
 $("#tabs-1").off("click").on("click",function(){ alert("test");});
```

This code works when clicking the tab area for the `tabs-1`, however i want the alertbox to show when only the tab header (`Nunc tincidunt` text) is clicked.

Any help is so much appreciated.

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ok7svxm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just target the `a` tag directly:

```
$("a[href='#tabs-1']").on("click",function(){ alert("test");});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ok7svxm/1/

Comment: Thanks. just want to ask, is this working on IE8?(Wont be able to try it now so im asking.)

Comment: Yes, it'll work in IE8 so long as you use a version of jQuery < 2.0